# How to merge many rasters with a python script within QGIS using GDAL?

Tags: python, merge, raster, gdal, qgis

I have many rasters that im trying to combine in order to produce contours. They are in the .bil format so I understand that i need to translate them using gdal first but none of my attempts have worked.

I have tried to used gdal_translate and gdal_merge with no success. Below is the a sample of two .bils i tried to merge.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import gdal

#imagea ='C:\\Users\\jeswa\\Desktop\\New folder\\N34_E\\n34_e024_1arc_v3.bil'
#imageb ='C:\\Users\\jeswa\\Desktop\\New folder\\N34_E\\n34_e025_1arc_v3.bil'
#output = 'C:\\Users\\jeswa\\Desktop\\test'
#subprocess.call(['gdal_merge', '-o', output, imagea, imageb])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```